# Mysql FullText Search Case-insensitive

Tags: mysql, case, case-insensitive, full-text-search

I have table products_discription  from OpenCart.
I created new search engine. Everything is okey, except that is case sensitive.
How I can make it insensitive.
I readed in Mysql Documentation I must change  utf8_bin to utf8_general_ci.
But how to make it, without deleting all indexes.
Its not only one table. I'm looking for  at  4 tables. Every table has  around  4 -5  indexes.
The site brings non-stop information. Loss of information is simply not acceptable.
I was wondering if there is a way to extract keys to delete, and change the encoding. Then add them again with just one application. As such, I think that there will be no data loss.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_description` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `short_description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `meta_keyword` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `tag` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `custom_title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`language_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `tag` (`tag`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_namerel` (`name`,`description`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`,`short_description`,`description`,`meta_description`,`meta_keyword`,`tag`,`custom_title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I suspect you'll have to recreate all indexes you want case insensitive, since the indexes now index lower- and uppercase differently, but now they should be indexed the same for quick access.

Comment: Can I do it with 1  command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried searching in boolean mode?

Comment: SELECT `product_description`.`product_id` ,`product_description`.`name`,`product_description`.`description`, `product`.`model`,`product`.`image`,`product`.`price`,`product`.`viewed`, (SELECT AVG(rating) FROM review WHERE product_id = product_description.product_id) AS `rating` FROM `product_description` , `product` WHERE `product_description`.`product_id` IN (SELECT `product_id` FROM `product_description` WHERE MATCH (`product_description`.`name`) AGAINST ("раница" IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH (`product_description`.`custom_title`) AGAINST ("раница" IN BOOLEAN MODE ))

This is my searchQuery

Answer (score -1):

I deleted all  index keys and change encoding, after that I set new index keys.